# Programming JNI with Delphi

Tags: delphi, java-native-interface

Can I use Delphi to program to the [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_native_interface)? From reading [Essential JNI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136798950) it seems possible if you make sure you are using the C calling convention. Anyone done this before? I would appreciate tips on tools that will help e.g. a tool to convert the C header file of Javah to Delphi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can check these projects and articles to use the JNI (Java Native Interface) and delphi

- [Delphi-Java Bridge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/djbridge/)
- [Java Native Interface and Delphi](http://home.pacifier.com/~mmead/jni/delphi/informant/di200309kw.htm) - Going Native -  by Keith Wood
- [Using the Java Native Interface with Delphi](http://home.pacifier.com/~mmead/jni/delphi/)

Answer (score 4):

Besides JNI there is also Java Native Access (JNA) which requires much less setup (no C header files) so your Delphi DLL functions (and callbacks) can be used directly from Java:

[JNA Homepage](https://github.com/twall/jna)

> JNA provides Java programs easy access
>   to native shared libraries (DLLs on
>   Windows) without writing anything but
>   Java code—no JNI or native code is
>   required. This functionality is
>   comparable to Windows' Platform/Invoke
>   and Python's ctypes. Access is dynamic
>   at runtime without code generation.

Comment: Indeed, yes this is a brilliant product and I know its widely used, for example IntelliJ Idea uses it. I want to do COM interop however and would like make use of the nice Delphi support for that while at the same time provide a basic facade to my Java code.