# How to convert String to PWideString in Delphi for JNA consumption

Tags: java, string, delphi, dll, jna

I'm creating a DLL in **Delphi** and the method is like this:

```
function teste3 : PWideString; stdcall;
  var
    _string : string;
  begin
    _string := 'teste';
    Result := PWideString(_string);
  end;
```

Then i'm trying to call this method using JNA lib in **JAVA**. The code that call the method in JAVA is like this:

```
System.out.println(TDLL.getInstance().teste3());
```

But when the return of the call is only the char `t` the rest of the text is not comming.

How can I convert the `String` to `PWideString` without losing all the chars?

**Obs**: I tried returning PWideChar too but the result is the same.

Comment: The string goes out of scope as soon as the function ends. If your goal is to pass a const string, declare `const _string : widestring = 'teste'`

Comment: it's just a test, but imagine that I'll process something than return this in the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi's `PWideString` type is a pointer to a `WideString`.  If you return such a pointer to Java, Java won't know what to do with it.  You would need to return a raw `PAnsiChar` or `PWideChar` instead (prefer the latter, since Java strings are Unicode), but then you have an issue to deal with - memory management.

If you return a pointer to a statically allocated string, or at least a dynamically allocated string that outlives the function, you can return a pointer to the character data directly:

Delphi:

```pascal
const
  _string : WideString = 'teste'; // or UnicodeString in D2009+

function teste3 : PWideChar; stdcall;
begin
  Result := PWideChar(_string);
end;
```

Or:

```pascal
var
  _string : WideString; // or UnicodeString

function teste3 : PWideChar; stdcall;
begin
  _string = 'teste'
  Result := PWideChar(_string);
end;
```

Java:

```java
public class TDLL extends Library {
  TDLL INSTANCE = (TDLL) Native.loadLibrary("myjnalib.dll", TDLL.class);
  public static TDLL getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }
  WString teste3();
}

System.out.println(TDLL.getInstance().teste3().toString());
```

However, if you need to dynamically allocate the string, you have to free that memory inside the same DLL or else it will be leaked.  Java can't free the memory for you, since it doesn't know how the memory was allocated.

To get around that, you should redesign the DLL function to accept a memory buffer as input, and then you can use JNA's [`Memory`](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Memory.html) class on the Java side.  Have the DLL fill the memory buffer, and then Java can call the [`Memory.getString()`](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Memory.html#getString%28long,%20Boolean%29) method to read the output data into a native Java `string`:

Delphi:

```pascal
function teste3(buffer: PByte; bufsize: Integer) : Integer; stdcall;
var
  _string : WideString; // or UnicodeString
  MaxChars: Integer;
begin
  _string := 'teste';
  MaxChars := (bufsize div sizeof(WideChar)) - 1;
  StrLCopy(PWideChar(buffer), PWideChar(_string), MaxChars);
  Result := Min(Length(_string), MaxChars);
end;
```

Java:

```java
public class TDLL extends Library {
  TDLL INSTANCE = (TDLL) Native.loadLibrary("myjnalib.dll", TDLL.class);
  public static TDLL getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }
  int teste3(Memory buf, int bufsize);
}

Memory buf = new Memory(10);
TDLL.getInstance().teste3(buf, buf.size());
System.out.println(buf.getString(0, true));
```

That being said, you might consider switching to JNI instead (see [Programming JNI with Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725691/)), because then the DLL can use Java's own memory manager to dynamically allocate and return an actual Java `string` object, and then Java can free it normally as needed:

Delphi:

```pascal
function Java_TDLL_test3(env: PJNIEnv; obj: JObject): JString; stdcall;
var
  _string : WideString; // or UnicodeString
begin
  _string := 'teste';
  Result := env^.NewString(env, PJChar(PWideChar(_string)), Length(_string));
end;
```

Java:

```java
public class TDLL {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("myjnalib");
  }

  public native string test3();
}

System.out.println(new TDLL().teste3());
```

Comment: Just the last example was not so clear for me. After declare the Java_TDLL_test3 method in Delphi, how i'll use this in JAVA? In your example you're not sending the PJNIEnv and JObject arguments.

Comment: @LeonardoGaldioli those parameters are passed automatically by Java itself. It is part of the "magic" hookup behind the `native` specifier. There are tons of tutorials on how JNI works, that is out of scope of this question.

Comment: So intead of using JNA i should try to use JNI and use that lib for using the java types in delphi right?
And if I have more parameters i won't have the "Invalid memory access" error?